React Leaflet Marker Change Rerenders Every Other Marker Causing Performance Issues
I'm trying to build a quick leaflet map akin to Apartments.com. It's a map with a bunch of markers (up to 2000 in my case) and it will have a sidebar with more in-depth details about the markers that are currently visible. When I mouse over one of the items in the sidebar, I want the marker on the map to change colors. I do this by having a hoveredMarker state and passing it into the sidebar to be updated whenever I hover over something new. What ends up happening is that the MapComponent rerenders every single marker and that can cause performance issues when there are 1000+ markers on screen. How can I fix this? Is there a way for me to update only one marker without making it rerender everything?
This is a bit of a passion project for me so any feedback is appreciated. I can go more in-depth if needed!
I have tried using useMemo but when I tried it it didn't fix performance.
export default function MapComponent() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState<Map | null>(null)
  const [hoveredMarker, setHoveredMarker] = useState<MarkerData | null>(null)
  const [visibleMarkers, setVisibleMarkers] = useState<MarkerData[]>([])

  const recalculateMarkers = (m: Map) => {
    const mapBounds = m.getBounds()
    const northEast = mapBounds.getNorthEast()
    const southWest = mapBounds.getSouthWest()
    const tempVisibleMarkers = currentMarkers.filter(
      (marker) => {
        return (
          marker.latitude <= northEast.lat &&
          marker.latitude >= southWest.lat &&
          marker.longitude <= northEast.lng &&
          marker.longitude >= southWest.lng
        )
      }
    )

    setVisibleMarkers(tempVisibleMarkers)
  }

  map?.on('zoom', () => {
    recalculateMarkers(map)
  })
  map?.on('resize', () => {
    recalculateMarkers(map)
  })
  map?.on('drag', () => {
    recalculateMarkers(map)
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      recalculateMarkers(map)
    }
  }, [map])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <MapContainer
          ref={setMap}
        >
          <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
          {visibleMarkers.map((data) =>
            data.url !== hoveredMarker?.url ? (
              <Marker
                key={data.url}
                position={[data.latitude, data.longitude]}
                icon={greenIcon}
              />
            ) : null
          )}
          {hoveredMarker && (
            <Marker
              key={hoveredMarker.url}
              position={[
                hoveredMarker.latitude,
                hoveredMarker.longitude
              ]}
              icon={redIcon}
              zIndexOffset={1000}
            />
          )}
        </MapContainer>
        <MarkerList
          visibleMarkers={visibleMarkers}
//------->setHoveredMarker={setHoveredMarker}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function MarkerList({
  visibleMarkers,
  setHoveredMarker
}: MapListProps) {
  const TabButton = ({ visibleMarker }: TabButtonProps) => {
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)

    return (
      <div
        key={visibleMarker.url}
        onMouseOver={() => {
          setHover(true)
// this set state is causing the map the rerender every time I hover a new item
//------->setHoveredMarker(visibleMarker)
        }}
        onMouseOut={() => {
          setHover(false)
          setHoveredMarker(null)
        }}
      >
         ...
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {visibleMarkers
        .map((visibleMarker) => (
          <TabButton
            visibleMarker={visibleMarker}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}


